# Windows 10 ( mobile) doesn´t create a hyperlink in a SMS url

Tags: windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

I´m trying to call my application ( myapp://mypage ) via a link in a SMS. It works in older versions, but when Windows 10 reads the SMS, it doesn't create the hyperlink to the user click on it. It only shows the link as text. 
When the text in the SMS starts with "http://" or  "www." it works fine in Windows 10. The problem occurs only when it calls an application. Someone knows how to handle it?